# Table Elements not aligning well in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4

List element is not aligning center in **Internet explorer**. But in **Chrome** the element is centered. Attached is the sample code. I am using **Bootstrap CSS Framework** for all the classes.
Here is the JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/8cunpsvy/

[image: the result in IE]
[image: the result in Chrome]
HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th class="w-25" scope="col"></th>
                <th style="width: 54%" scope="col"></th>
                <th style="width: 10%" scope="col">Actual</th>
                <th style="width: 1%;" scope="col">Status</th>
                <th style="width: 10%" scope="col">Expected</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="text-center">2/13/2019</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <ul class="status-circle"><li></li></ul>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.status-circle {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    line-height: 0;
}

.status-circle li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #737373;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting width in `td`? you already set width in `th`, so the following `td` will have the same width as the `th`

Comment: I'll be removing it. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the element inside into div and transferred all the styles from the li element also adding content.
HTML:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table-sm table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="text-center">
                <th class="w-25" scope="col"></th>
                <th style="width: 54%" scope="col"></th>
                <th style="width: 10%" scope="col">Actual</th>
                <th style="width: 1%;" scope="col">Status</th>
                <th style="width: 10%" scope="col">Expected</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="text-center">2/13/2019</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <div class="div-status-circle"></div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div-status-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    content: "";
    background: #737373;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8twnzumc/)

```
.status-circle {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 1px solid #000;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
background: #737373;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

instead of using list element  for a single item you can achieve this by using a div or span